# C# HTTPWebRequest Multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am new to threading. I am trying to send HTTP Web Request using multi threading, I am not able to acheive what I need. 
My requirement is to send request to thousands of same or different websites and parse the response i get it from httpwebrequest. 
In the below code, i am sending 2 simulteaneous threads, I am looking for ten simultaneously threads.

```
namespace threading
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate string UrlFetcher(string url);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 1;
        UrlFetcher u = new UrlFetcher(Fetch);
        UrlFetcher u = new UrlFetcher(Fetch1);
        string pageURL = "http://www.google.com";

        while (i <= 1000)
        {
            u.BeginInvoke(pageURL, new AsyncCallback(AfterFetch), "this is state");
            i++;
            u.BeginInvoke(pageURL, new AsyncCallback(AfterFetch1), "this is state");
            i++;
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    }

    static string Fetch(string pageURL)
    {
        HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pageURL);
        WebReq.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
        Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
        string myString = _Answer.ReadToEnd();
        return myString;
    }

    void AfterFetch(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        string a;

        AsyncResult async = (AsyncResult)result;
        UrlFetcher fetcher = (UrlFetcher)async.AsyncDelegate;
        a = fetcher.EndInvoke(result).ToString();

        Regex regx = new Regex(@"<td>([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.(com|net)</td>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection mactches = regx.Matches(a);
        foreach (Match match in mactches)
        {
            string pattern = @"<(.|\n)*?>";
            string r = Regex.Replace(match.Value, pattern, string.Empty);
            textBox3.AppendText(r);
        }
    }

    static string Fetch1(string pageURL)
    {
        HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pageURL);
        WebReq.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
        Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
        string myString = _Answer.ReadToEnd();
        return myString;
    }

    void AfterFetch1(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        string a;

        AsyncResult async = (AsyncResult)result;
        UrlFetcher fetcher = (UrlFetcher)async.AsyncDelegate;
        a = fetcher.EndInvoke(result).ToString();

        Regex regx = new Regex(@"<td>([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.(com|net)</td>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection mactches = regx.Matches(a);
        foreach (Match match in mactches)
        {
            string pattern = @"<(.|\n)*?>";
            string r = Regex.Replace(match.Value, pattern, string.Empty);
            textBox3.AppendText(r);
        }
    }
}
}
```

If anyone would correct the above code, it is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I would say

- Abolish your delegate
- Set up a WebRequest in the loop
- Use the async version of Getting the response `(Begin/End)GetResponse`
- Keep your async callback reentrant (independent of any instance state) and make it use the result from the "End" call and any state you pass in (e.g. the WebRequest itself)

That should more or less work

Comment: +1 - exactly what needs to be done. The async delegate approach helps pretty much nothing to make the code perform well, because each request would still block a thread, which isn't the case if the async operations on the WebRequest/WebResponse/Stream/... are used instead.

Comment: Since I am new to threading, Can someone correct the above code using end response in appropriate place.

Comment: Additionally, dispose the WebResponse and the Stream (returned from GetResponseStream) so that connections you're no longer using are closed properly.